# New form fields with previous data displayed

Tags: forms, mobile, tablet

I need to create a mobile form (clients target platform is iOS (iPad Mini)) that has fields to add information for the current process, however the form needs to display the previous values entered.

[image: Here's an example mock:]

Could I get some ideas of (more than likely) better ways to show this information?

Thanks.

Meant to add - there may be no previous details, so this section of the form could be blank and look terrible.

Comment: What is wrong with what you currently have? How do you know it's not working as needed? We're going to need a bit more detail here about your situation.

Comment: I don't know it's not working, this was more of an 'opinion' question, I did forget to add a little bit of information, which I've updated the original post. You could be right, I may have hit UX design panacea straight off the bat!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what your question actually is about but a bunch of thoughts:

1. If there's a rationale for displaying the previous value then one should always be able to see it -- regardless of whether the screen is in landscape or portrait mode. LinkedIn does this when editing your profile in a secondary language by showing your original language entry below the one you're editing. See the example below: [image: Example of LinkedIn multi-language profile editing]
2. Is it obvious to the user what should be typed in those fields? I.e., is it names, coordinates, identifiers, etc? If not, consider a default or example value displayed in italics in the field and removed when the field receives the keyboard focus (e.g., aaaa/mm/dd). Note though that on some platforms [this can be considered an accessibility issue](http://www.cssglance.com/news/accessibility-of-pre-filled-input-fields/). You need to think about when an example is needed (probably when there is no previous content) and it may work better to put the example where you'd normally put the previous value
3. Do you need to have "Customer" written everywhere? Is there any ambiguity in removing it, at least for "Representative Position"?

Answer (score 0):

If it's not important that the old data be visible at all times, you could display the previous data within the fields themselves, then blank the data out when it's field gains focus. If there was no previous data, then the field simply remains blank. If the User cancels the input, the field is then repopulated with the old data.

If it is important that the old data be visible at all times, you could add a label above or below each field which displays the old data. It's much easier to fit short and wide objects on a vertical plane the a horizontal one in a pleasant way.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can prepopulate the previous datas in the fields. Anyways the fields are editable. So you need not delete anything when the field gains focus. If he needs to edit the previous value he can type it in the field deleting the previous data. If previous data is not there you can show an empty field. This will work :)